# background pixels flickering on bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Anybody know bootstrap modal background issue?
flickering background pixels

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/)

HTML

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks fine on my machine, have you tested on another computer/browser?

Comment: @AVAVT Yes, I have checked in other monitors
1024x768 fine
1920x1080 not fine

Comment: When I resize to screen size full screen to 300px then face this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed .fade.in opacity property on *bootstrap.min.css* from `1` to `0.99`: `.fade.in{opacity:0.99}`

and that solved the problem while a better solution appears.

*** update***
try this on bootstrap.min.css

.fade.in{opacity:1;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bug in bootstrap, 
i got the same issue and i found out that it caused by elements on the page that got opacity property.
i manage to reproduce it on bootstrap site 
hope it will help you.

[image]

furthermore, it happen only on chrome.

Comment: my issue resolved to above 'EmilioRamirez24' answer.

Try this I think you helpful...

Your bootstrap.min.css
    Replace ".fade.in{opacity:1;}" to ".fade.in{opacity:1;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}"